# How can you select multiple css attributes in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I'm a new jquery user, and I need some help.

I'm trying to change a css :hover attribute of a last child div element upon a click of that div. More specifically, I have a nav-bar div with some child div buttons in it. The child divs are all a par of the same class so that when I hover over them...a border-width attribute changes. I would like it so that when I click last child div, the border color is changed, but still only shows when the mouse is hovering...and when I click it again, I would like the original border attributes defined in the css to retake effect.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
$("div.navbar:last").click(function(){    
    if ($("div#details").is(":hidden")){    
        $("div#details").fadeIn(100);    
        $("div.navbar:hover").css("border-bottom-color","#ee4444");
    } else {
        $("div#details").fadeOut(100);
        $("div.navbar").css("border-bottom-color","#88ddff");
    }   
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: jQuery does'nt support pseudo selectors.

Comment: @adeneo More accurately, JavaScript cannot alter pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the `:hover` selector in jQuery. You should avoid using the `.css()` method, and instead use `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `toggleClass` to change DOM state.

Actual CSS can then take over and use the classes as styling hooks to change how the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

As Adeneo stated, you can't use psuedo selectors (like `:hover`) in jQuery.  If you want to attach a hover event in jQuery you could however use something like the following:

```
$("#myElement").on('hover', function() {
    alert("I've been hovered over!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the pseudoclass on a secondary class which you add on click

JS

```
  $("div.navbar:last").click(function(){    
    if ($("div#details").is(":hidden")){    
        $("div#details").fadeIn(100);    
        $("div.navbar").addClass("hoverBottom");
    } else {
        $("div#details").fadeOut(100);
        $("div.navbar").css("border-bottom-color","#88ddff");
    }  
    });
```

CSS

```
.hoverBottom:after {
  border-bottom-color","#ee4444";
}
```